# Amob integration in adapter class issue

Tags: java, android

I want to integrate admob in adapter class but it is giving me following error. I also put context but still the problem is there. Please let me know what should I put instead of context? I have searched but I did not found any solution. The context is already in the interstitial show method with mCTX which is context in adapter class.

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {
    private Context mCtx;
    public Context ct;
    private final List<Category> categoryList;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    public CategoriesAdapter(Context mCt, List<Category> categoryList) {
        this.mCtx = mCt;
        this.ct=mCt;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        MobileAds.initialize(mCtx, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        InterstitialAd.load(mCtx,
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712",
                adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i("TAG", "onAdLoaded");
                    }
                   @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        // Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false);

        return new CategoryViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Category c = categoryList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(c.name);
        Picasso.with(mCtx).load(c.thumb).into(holder.imageView);
}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }
   class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_cat_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int p = getAdapterPosition();
            Category c = categoryList.get(p);

            Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, QuotesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("category", c.name);

            mCtx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
public void fullscads()
    {        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(mCtx);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to Activity
            mInterstitialAd.show(mCtx);
                                 ^                                                                                                             This error is showing.

Comment: From where you call this CategoriesAdapter, is it from Fragment?

Comment: Yes bro I am calling this in fragment. Do you want to see ?

Comment: you can use getActivity() method of Fragment.

Comment: mInterstitialAd.show(getActivity());  But this will not work in adapter, because i am placing this on click event in adapter class. and i am using mCTX instead of getActivity, Please let me know what changes i should make in adapter class.

Comment: It should be mInterstitialAd.show(((YourFrangmentName)mCtx)getActivity());

Comment: Fragment name is CategoryFragment so the code should be like mInterstitialAd.show(((CategoryFragment)mCtx)getActivity());   is this correct bro ?

Comment: Seems fine. If you still face any issue, please paste logcat error.